# share text and image using QLPreviewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, qlpreviewcontroller

I have implemented QLPreviewController for social sharing i.e. What's app, Facebook etc. It is working great whenever I send particular image or text. But my requirement is to send the image and text simultaneously with one click. And I didn't find any method to send both at once. With the following method only one data can be shared either text or image.

```
QLPreviewController *previewController = [[QLPreviewController alloc] init];
previewController.dataSource = self;
previewController.delegate = self;
previewController.currentPreviewItemIndex = indexPath.row;
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:previewController animated:YES];
```

If I use UIActivityViewController then it doesn't allow user to share the content with What's app.

Please look upon this issue, if some has any solution, please share with me.

Thanks!